# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to find the Sql script file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, configuration-wizard

Getting below error while running SharePoint configuration wizard on SharePoint 2016 Farm.

> 07/29/2019 14:14:04  15  ERR            Task upgradebootstrap has failed with an unknown exception 
>   07/29/2019 14:14:04  15  ERR            Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Action 16.0.1.0 of Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Database.Extension.Upgrade.PDEUpgradeSequence failed. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Failed to extract the schema version from the backcompat sql script ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to find the Sql script file at D:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Sql\Project Server\Core\contentdatabasebackcompat.sql
>      at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProjectDatabaseSqlScript.GetInstance(String scriptName, Boolean isDDL)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Database.Extension.Upgrade.PDEUpgradeSequence.GetRestoredDatabaseVersion()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Database.Extension.Upgrade.PDEUpgradeSequence.GetRestoredDatabaseVersion()
>      at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Database.Extension.Upgrade.PDECreateSchemaObjectsUpgrader.Upgrade()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.Upgrade()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.Upgrade()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.RunUpgraders(Object o, List`1 lstClass)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.BootStrap(Guid sessionId, SPUpgradeOperationFlags flags)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeBootstrapTask.Run()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Answer (score 0):

Try to do as follows:

1.Run the following in the SharePoint 2016 Management Shell to upgrade the compoments in the Central Administration database:

```
Get-SPWebApplication <Central Administration URL> | Get-SPContentDatabase | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
```

2.Run the SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard from the command line:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources
```